# export html to word using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have used JavaScript code to export html div to word and it works correct in office 2016 and office 2010 but in office 2007 and office 2003 I have problem where I have hidden parts which shown in conditions it works fine in office 2016 and office 2010 but it doesn't work in office 2007 it's always hidden

I use this code to hide the `<div>`

```
style display:none
```

In one of the condition I turn it to `display:block`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I think you need to show some more code....

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your word processor

Comment: what do you mean by upgrade your word processor

Comment: i have <div id="d1" style="display:none"><p>aaaa</p></div> and i have 2 button with yes and no in case yes i change display to block using javascrpit it works fine with word 2016 and 2010 but no sense in office 2007

Comment: thanks all i have solved it with some JavaScript tricks